# Auto-sort column Google Spreadsheet on incoming Google Form response

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

How can I get the Google Spreadsheet to automatically order the incoming form responses alphabetically (2nd column)?

I know how to do this manually or by going in and editing a cell, but cannot get it to do this as an onevent for incoming response.

Answer (score 2):

I have one suggestion: on the next empty column on your Form Response:

```
=Query(range; "select * where x <> '' order by x" , 1)
```

Where `range` is the range of the responses and `x` is the column that you want to sort. Hide the columns where the answers are automatically inserted.

Comment: =Query('Form Responses 1'!B1:C300; "select * where C <> '' order by C" , 1)
WOW COOL! I needed to still figure how to but what where but i saw logic in other examples. THX :)
& 1 ROW needs to be name couse its static in formula.